# In pandas, is there a way to pivot rows to the end of other rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a pandas dataframe which is the result of a questionnaire answered by families. The data looks like this:

```
pos     gen     parent  child   famid   f       g       h
1       2       200681          68      1       2       3
0       1       100681          68      1       2       3 
1       2               200691  69      1       2       3 
0       1       100691          69      1       2       3  
1       2               200701  70      1       2       3 
2       2               200702  70      1       2       3 
3       2               200703  70      1       2       3  
0       1       100701          70      1       2       3  
1       2               200711  71      1       2       3 
2       2               200712  71      1       2       3 
0       1       100711          71      1       2       3
```

What I want to do is take all children and the children's information in f through j and append new columns (f1 - h1 for sibling 1, f2- h2 for sibling2 and so on) to the end of the parent column. The result would look like this:

```
pos   gen   parent  child1  child2 child3 famid  f g h f1 g1 h2 f2 g2 h2 f3...
0     1     100681  200681                68     1 2 3 1  2  3 
0     1     100691  200691                69     1 2 3 1  2  3 
0     1     100701  200701  200702 200703 70     1 2 3 1  2  3  1  2  3  1 ... 
0     1     100711  200711  200712        71     1 2 3 1  2  3  1  2  3
```

So the goal is to make family Id unique for each column and use the pos column to split up the members of the family into their new rows.

I have been messing around with pivots and stacking, but I haven't quite found what I need to get this done. Not sure if a pivot is the best way to go about this so I am open to suggestions.

Comment: It's not clear to me how your splitting the children, what determines child 1 to 3?

Comment: The 'pos' column represents the order of the family members. 0 representing the caregiver and then the numbers (1-3)  representing the siblings. The number assigned to each sibling is arbitrary and I believe is solely based off of when they were entered into the data.

Comment: How are `f1`, `g1`, `h2`, `f2` etc created?

Comment: Sorry it's still not clear, i'm not sure how `f1`+ are generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This takes several steps, I solved it this way:

1. Groupby on `famid` and aggregate the string values with `','.join`
2. At the same time, rename the columns
3. Create a df which has the rows with `pos == 0`
4. Concat the created dataframe to a final dataframe

```
cols_agg = ['child', 'f', 'g', 'h']

df_group1 = df.groupby('famid').agg({cols_agg[0]: ','.join,
                                     cols_agg[1]: ','.join,
                                     cols_agg[2]: ','.join,
                                     cols_agg[3]: ','.join}).reset_index()

groups =[]
for col in enumerate(cols_agg):
    groups.append(df_group1[col[1]].str.split(',', expand=True).rename({0:cols_agg[col[0]]+'0',
                                                                        1:cols_agg[col[0]]+'1',
                                                                        2:cols_agg[col[0]]+'2',
                                                                        3:cols_agg[col[0]]+'3'}, axis=1))

df_last = df[df.pos=='0'].iloc[:, :3].reset_index(drop=True)

groups_df = pd.concat(groups, axis=1)
groups_df = pd.concat([df_group1.iloc[:, :1], groups_df], axis=1)
df_final = pd.concat([df_last, groups_df], axis=1).fillna('')
```

**Output**

```
print(df_final)
  pos gen  parent famid  child0  child1  child2 child3 f0 f1 f2 f3 g0 g1 g2 g3 h0 h1 h2 h3 
0   0   1  100681    68                                 1  1        2  2        3  3         
1   0   1  100691    69  200691                         1  1        2  2        3  3         
2   0   1  100701    70  200701  200702  200703         1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  3   
3   0   1  100711    71  200711  200712                 1  1  1     2  2  2     3  3  3
```